# Simple JQuery click-and-show doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this simple bit of JQuery to show/hide a div by clicking on the link, I've used the same code a few times before and it worked perfectly but now all of a sudden it refuses to work.

JQuery is properly included and the page doesn't give a Javascript error (or any other error for that matter).

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(function() {
       $('#addnew').css('display', 'none');
       $('#shownew').click(function() {
           $('#addnew').toggle();
           return false;
       });        
   });
</script>
```

HTML (link):

```
<a href='#' id='shownew'>Add News Item</a>
```

HTML (div):

```
<div id="addnew">
<form id="new_news" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="news.php" method="post">
Title:
<br/><input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
<p>Image (optional, will be shown after first paragraph)
<br/><input type="hidden" name="size" value="2000000"><input type="file" name="photo">
<p>Article body:
<br/><textarea cols='40' rows='5' maxlength='5000' name='body' id='body'></textarea>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

What could I possibly be missing here? As you see from the JQuery, the div is hidden to begin with. When I remove the line that says `$('#addnew').css('display', 'none');` the div is displayed correctly, but the link still doesn't toggle it on and off.

Comment: [Your posted code works](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XLNga/). The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Your code works perfectly here. Are you _sure_ jQuery is included correctly? Copy/pase of your code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xcXAq/)

Comment: Works fine when I throw it up on jsFiddle (seems saving there still is down). Do you have other scripts running or have you re-used the same ID?

Comment: It works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/Xtvuq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is #showNew element present in the DOM before onload? If it is not then your code will not work. If that is the case following code will help you.

```
$(document).on('click', '#shownew',function() {
       $('#addnew').toggle();
       return false;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I reloaded the page a few minutes later and it worked. No idea what was wrong. I know the code was good from the beginning.

Comment: In such case this question don't have any value - please delete it.